# Can Windows Bootmgr load Ubuntu without needing a second reboot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, ubuntu-mate, mbr

Note:
In this question I am **not** asking if it is possible to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu.

I have Windows 10 on an SSD in a DVD caddy (/dev/sdb) and Ubuntu mate on an HDD (/dev/sda). Both are Legacy BIOS/MBR on a Dell Laptop.

Is it possible to have this scenario?
I turn on my laptop and I get a Windows 10 boot menu giving me the choice of Windows 10 and Ubuntu. If  I choose Ubuntu then it just loads Ubuntu.

With my current set up when I turn on my laptop the Windows 10 boot menu gives me the choice of Windows 10 and Ubuntu.... IF I choose Ubuntu my laptop first does a quick reboot then I get a GRUB2 menu where I can choose Ubuntu or Windows.

Can Windows Bootmgr just load Ubuntu without needing a second reboot? Is there anyway to make this happen? Other methods or boot managers?

**What I have tried**
I tried placing the Ubuntu bootloader code in /dev/sda and also in /dev/sda1. I was thinking that putting the GRUB2 stuff in a partition might allow Windows to load the Linux OS without needing an extra boot after I select Ubuntu from the Windows bootmgr menu.

Maybe it's just not possible?

Cheers.

Comment: Since this is about the Windows configuration it would be better if it was asked at https://superuser.com/

Comment: OK but I think my question covers the concept of booting Linux OS in general. So I was hoping someone here might be able to help.

Comment: But I don't see configuring Ubuntu in your question.  You can use GRuB which can load Windows without rebooting.  But configuring Windows bootloader is about Windows.

Comment: Windows cannot boot Ubuntu/grub without third party tools. It almost sounds like you have Windows in BIOS mode & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode or vice-versa, so you have to use UEFI menu to boot. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible.  Grub only boots working Windows and can only boot other installs in same boot mode UEFI or BIOS as grub is booted.

Comment: @Terrance Thank you. From testing I noticed that GRUB2 CAN load Windows directly but apparently not the other way around. @oldfred I double checked and both Win 10 and Ubuntu are installed on MBR/Legacy BIOS. I have no `/sys/firmware/efi` file in Ubtunu either. But to clarify I'm not asking if Windows can boot Ubuntu. I already used EasyBCD and got dual boot working. I'm asking if Windows can load Ubuntu without needing a second reboot which I noticed is currently the case. I read it's because `..the grub bootloader can only be loaded by the system BIOS when the computer boots.`